# Thresholding function - No gradients provided for any variable

Tags: python, tensorflow

What I am trying to achieve is, get the output layer of a neural network, perform a thresholding operation after normalization of that value and the cost function would be the difference in the binary output layer value and my class label. I keep getting the above error - **No gradients provided for any variable**.

Here's Input part of the code:

```
# Input and Expected Output of the neural networks
xs = tf.placeholder("float32", [None, n_features], name='XtoNN')
ys = tf.placeholder("float32", [None, 1], name='YfromNN')

# Hidden Layer
weightsH = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([n_features, neurons_in_hlayer], mean=0,
                                     stddev=1 / np.sqrt(n_features)), name='weights1')
biasesH = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([neurons_in_hlayer],mean=0, stddev=1 / np.sqrt(n_features)), name='biases1')
yValH = tf.nn.sigmoid(tf.add(tf.matmul(xs, weightsH),biasesH), name='activationLayer1')


# Output Layer
WeightsO = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([neurons_in_hlayer, n_classes], mean=0, stddev = 1/np.sqrt(n_features)),
                                           name='weightsOut')
biasesO = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([n_classes], mean=0, stddev=1 / np.sqrt(n_features)), name='biasesOut')
yPred = tf.cast(tf.add(tf.matmul(yValH, WeightsO), biasesO), tf.float32)

# Cost function
redYPred = tf.div(tf.subtract(yPred, tf.reduce_min(yPred)),
                  tf.subtract(tf.reduce_max(yPred), tf.reduce_min(yPred)))
binaryYPred = tf.cast(tf.to_int32(redYPred > tf.reduce_mean(redYPred)), tf.float32)
cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(binaryYPred-ys, name='Cost'))

# Optimizer
train = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate).minimize(cost)
```

And the session of the model:

```
startTime = datetime.now()
# Session
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    # sess.run(tf.local_variables_initializer())
    saver = tf.train.Saver()
    for i in range(training_epochs):
        for j in range(n_samples):
            # Run NN
            sess.run([cost, train], feed_dict={xs: X_train[j, :].reshape(1, n_features),
                                               ys: Y_train[j].reshape(1,n_classes)})
        currentEpochCost = sess.run(cost, feed_dict={xs: X_train, ys: Y_train})
        print('Epoch ', (i+1), ': Cost = ', currentEpochCost)

    timeTaken = datetime.now() - startTime
    print('Time Taken: ', timeTaken)

    yTestPredict = sess.run(binaryYPred, feed_dict={xs: X_test})
```

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because you're adding an inherently nondifferentiable operation (hard thresholding) into your calculations. Since the threshold has no gradient, there's no gradient to backprop through your network.

Is there a specific reason you cannot use softmax to assign your output to one of the 2 output classes? There's a certain sense in which it's doing what you are trying to implement.

Once you've trained the network and it's outputting say 97%, 3% for the two classes, it's simple enough to binarize the outputs in test/use time.

Comment: I am trying to get a binary value which could be then converted into an image, a Saliency Binary image. I'm new to Tensorflow and as far as my knowledge goes, softmax squishes the values to make the sum 1. What I am trying to achieve is, get a float value from the Neural Network, Normalize it (Min-Max Normalisation) and then binarize it using a thresholding of the average value to compare it with my output binary image. I am not sure how to achieve this.

Comment: Can you please explain what "inherently nondifferentiable operation" means?

Comment: Like the idea of the derivative of a hard threshold function isn't defined I mean.

I'd just implement my network with softmax or sigmoid at the end of it and do the thresholding in a post inference step.